# how do i use jquery to increase the size of the particular div which is clicked. I have created divs using a loop

Tags: jquery

```
for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i += 5 ) {

                var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
                element.className = 'element';
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';

                $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".element").on("click",function(){
                     $( ".element" ).animate({
                    height:"200px"
                  }, 5000);
                  });
                });
                /////
                /*
                $( ".element" ).click(function() {
                  $( ".element" ).animate({
                    height:"200px"
                  }, 5000);
                });
```

this is the function i am using but using this it is changing only the last div...how can i update the particular div i click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this)`

```
$(".element").on("click",function(){
     $(this).animate({
        height:"200px"
     }, 5000);
});
```

If you create these divs dynamically, after page load use `event delegation`

```
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(){
     $(this).animate({
        height:"200px"
     }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: If the solution worked for you, please mark it as the answer. It helps other users who have similar queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` selector to get  the element which generated the event.

Implemented here : http://jsfiddle.net/pjpswLet/